# Camera following player opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, rotation, glm-math

I have been looking into this problem for a while now but I can't find a solution.
Right now my camera follows the players position correctly but the rotation of the camera goes wrong. If I only use one rotation it goes correctly, say of I rotate only along the x axis then it works fine. But the second I add another rotation say the 'y' things go wrong and the camera starts looking into the wrong direction.

Right now my camera only has a position and a rotation.

Here is some code.

```
glm::vec4 cameraPosition;

//This gives the camera the distance it keaps from the player.
cameraPosition.x = 0.0;
cameraPosition.y = 0.0;
cameraPosition.z = 20.0;
cameraPosition.w = 0.0;

// mStartingModel is the rotation matrix of the player.
glm::vec4 result = mStartingModel * cameraPosition;

//here I set the camera's position and rotation. The z rotation is given a extra 180 degrees so the camera is behind the player.
CameraHandler::getSingleton().getDefaultCamera()->setPosition(Vector3f(-player->mPosition.x + result.x, -player->mPosition.y + result.y, -player->mPosition.z + result.z), Vector3f(-(player->mRotation.x + 180), -player->mRotation.y, -player->mRotation.z) );
```

Also know I am using opengl, c++ and glm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a simple behavior, using `gluLookAt` is probably the simplest option! More infos [here](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm).

Seeing that you use `glm`, consider something like

```
glm::mat4 CameraMatrix = glm::LookAt(
    cameraPosition, // the position of your camera, in world space
    cameraTarget,   // where you want to look at, in world space
    upVector        // probably glm::vec3(0,1,0), but (0,-1,0) would make you looking upside-down, which can be great too
);
```

As taken from this site on [opengl tutorials](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/).

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, but for somereason it's not working with my camera, I guess my camera and this camera aren't compatible. I guess I can cut my camera out of the code and just use this but if there is an easyer way where I can keap my camera then that would be nice.

Comment: Maybe you should define what "your camera" is? I'm not familiar with this engine but I wrote camera systems in the past so I can probably help

Comment: Well right now it's a simple class which only holds the camera's position and rotation and has some set functions. Thats all it is right now. Honestly this part was given to me by a friend and I'm now doubting if I should keap it.

Comment: if all it does is hold the position and rotation, you can probably get rid of it :)

Comment: Yeah, thought so. DX Will have to rewrite quite some things now probebly. Thanks.